# How do I get the properties of a class that don't contain an attribute at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

So I have an `Attribute` I have created like so:

```
public class IgnoreFilter : Attribute
{
}
```

and I have a class that I have used it on also like so:

```
public class Customer
{

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string address;
    [IgnoreFilter]
    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set
        {
            address = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

I am now trying to get all of the properties at runtime from my `Customer` class that do not contain the `IgnoreFilter` attribute. So far I have...

```
customer.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Where(p => !p.CustomAttributes.Contains(typeof(IgnoreFilter)));
```

But the last line doesnt compile. I think I am on the right lines but I am probably missing something.

Can someone help get properties from a class that do not contain a custom attribute?

Comment: `Contains` is wrong. Use either `OfType<IgnoreFilter>().Any()` or just `Any(o => o.GetType() == typeof(IgnoreFilter))`

Comment: @Sinatr thanks, works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I ended up using:

```
customer.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Where(p =>  p.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(IgnoreFilter)) == null);
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault() ==  null` is `!Any()`.